# How to write arrays as column elements in a Data file in python and read it later in C?

Tags: python, c, arrays, data-files

I have two column dataset where each element of first column corresponds to an array. So basically my second column elements are arrays and first column elements are just numbers. I need to write it in a file using Python and later read it in C. I know HDF5 is the best way to store arrays but I was wondering if there is any other effective way of writing it in .csv/.dat/.txt file. Since I have to read it in C I can't use things like numpy.savez.

Comment: What's in the arrays?

Comment: Floats @meaning-matters

Answer (score 0):

I'd say write it to a text file. Per line put one first column number, followed by the second column's list of floats. Put a space between each element.

Assuming you know the maximum number of floats in the second column's array, and the maximum character length of each float, you can use `fgets()` to read the file line by line.